# os.startfile() also opens This PC

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python file that opens a folder if the password is correct, when I type in the proper password, not only does it open the requested folder, It also opens This PC.

how do I fix this?

edit: here is the script that uses os.startfile():

```
  if nameEL.get() == uname and pwordEL.get() == pword: # Checks to see if you entered the correct data.
    os.system('explorer')
    os.startfile(r"C:\Users\Dxoo\Desktop\FolderTest")
```

Comment: You need to provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's not enough information here for us to help you

Comment: I have edited the post, Is this sufficient information?

Comment: Have you tried it without the line os.system('explorer')?

Comment: acutally yes, I've gotten it to work, I'm beginning to think this question isn't necessary on this site :P